# Filter based on inputbox dates does not work

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I want to input start date and end date and have VBA to filter data entries in an excel table between the selected dates. This code however returns zero filtered entries. If I go the the filter in excel manually I find that it is configured correctly (dates placed into the filter criteria boxes). If I then click the OK button it filters fine. Any idea what mistake I made?

P.s. assume that the inputbox values are correctly formatted dates

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExpCsmLg()

' ExpCsmLg Makro
' this makro filters all data entries between two selected dates

Dim sdt As Date
Dim edt As Date

'sdt = InputBox("Choose Start date.")

'edt = InputBox("Choose End date.")


    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$Q$7992").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & sdt, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & edt


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work for me:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExpCsmLg()

' ExpCsmLg Makro
' this makro filters all data entries between two selected dates

Dim sdt As Date
Dim edt As Date

sdt = CDate(Application.InputBox("Choose Start date.", Type:=2))

edt = CDate(Application.InputBox("Choose End date.", Type:=2))


    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$Q$7992").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & sdt, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & edt


End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

**NOTE:**

The items in column **A** are real dates and not text values.